# Using R, is there a way to query rows of a sql file by using a vector of one column of numbers?

Tags: r, qsqlquery

I'm trying to obtain a query of rows of a sql file on R based on a column vector I already have. The sql file has a column of IDs while the rest has information based on the ID. I have a separate vector of the IDs that are of interest to me and I'm wondering if there's a way to query the rows of info and ID based on the vector of IDs I have.

I have tried

```
mydb <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "name.db") 

x = dbGetQuery(mydb, 'SELECT ID FROM table;')
```

and it obtains all of the IDs but I just want to get specific IDs based on a vector. I can't just input the character vector in there because I have a large amount of data.

```
a <- c(100,102,103,104..)



mydb <- dbConnect(RSQLite::SQLite(), "name.db") 

x = dbGetQuery(mydb, 'SELECT ID FROM table==a ;')
```

This does not only give me the IDs of the ones I want

Is there a way to query rows based on a vector of one column that has the desired ID #'s? Can we somehow get the system to output only the rows that contain the IDs that match the vector we give it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SQL query is a character string of SQL code. You  just need to build the query you want using R code:

Something like this:

```
a = 100:104
my_query = paste("SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN (", toString(a), ")")
my_query
# "SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN ( 100, 101, 102, 103, 104 )"

x = dbGetQuery(mydb, my_query)
```

`toString` comma-separates the input, which is appropriate here. `sprintf()` uses a "fill-in-the-blank" syntax, which is often more readable than `paste()` for stuff like this:

```
my_q = sprintf("SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN (%s)", toString(a))
my_q
# [1] "SELECT ID FROM TABLE WHERE ID IN (100, 101, 102, 103, 104)"
```